# From RAF fighter pilot to commercial pilot

Tags: military, commercial-aviation

I’d like to become an RAF fighter pilot for many reasons but to become a commercial pilot once I leave the RAF is not one of them. I am, however, curious to know, if I were to become an RAF pilot and served the mandatory service length (12 years) would I be able to then transition into a commercial pilot? How easy would this transition be? What steps would be involved (rough outline)? Would I need to attend a flight school as if I had no flying experience?

Any answers would be appreciated!

Comment: I assume you want this in context of an EASA license? Or are you looking for FAA? For the FAA, you would have to go through CPL/ATPL training and obtain those certifications, but you can credit most of your flying experience towards your required hours to obtain the ATPL and Instrument Rating, depending on what you are flying in the RAF.